# I'm trying to write a randomly patrolling AI for my 2D Platformer

Tags: unity, c#

I'm trying to write a randomly patrolling AI for my 2D Platformer. The AI already has a ground checker function which checks if there are tiles nearby or not. What I want to do is randomize its actions and create an illusion of a somewhat "sentient" enemy. What I tried to create below is using the built in RNG to make the enemy either jump, change direction, or keep moving.

The problem is, it doesn't seem to work properly. The enemy just jumps every second I want it to change behaviour. The change direction functions, however, don't occur as frequently. I need to know what I've done wrong here. Thanks.

```
void Update()
{   
      //RNG
      behaviour = Random.Range(0,3);
      jumpSpeed = Random.Range(1,5); 

      //clock
      timer += Time.deltaTime;
}

  //time
    private float waitTime = 2.0f;
    private float timer = 0.0f;

 void MoveRandomizer()
{
    if((Mathf.Round(timer%waitTime)) == 0)
    {
        if(behaviour == 0)
        {
        movingRight = false;
        
        }
        if(behaviour == 1)
        {   
        movingRight = true;
        
        }
        if(behaviour == 2)
        {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, jumpSpeed);
        }
    }   
    
}
```

Comment: Have you tried mapping out the results of `Random.Range(0,3)` over a period of time? Maybe the generator simply has a bias? Also *random* actions don't really create a sense of sentience normally, rather a sense of irregularity - if you want to make your AI seem more sentient, you should make it react to what is happening around it...

Comment: How/ when is MoveRandomizer called? What is movingRight doing? If you add MoveRandomizer to Update, you will see that Mathf.Round(timer%waitTime)) == 0 is true a lot of times per second, can it be that you just see the jump more often since the jump itself takes more time compared to your left/ right movement? That means jump is just as often as left/ right but takes longer to complete and it LOOKS like it is choosen more often

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compared to doing some custom timing with math, you could use InvokeRepeating (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.InvokeRepeating.html). Your code would change to something like this and gets called repeatedly.

```
private float waitTime = 2.0f;

void Start()
{
    InvokeRepeating("RandomMove", 0f, waitTime);
}

void RandomMove()
{
    int behaviour = Random.Range(0,3);
    switch (behaviour)
    {
        case 0: movingRight = false;
            break;
        case 1: movingRight = true;
            break;
        case 2:
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, Random.Range(1,5));
            break;
    }
}
```

But to make it more realistic, you should not have an even distribution of actions. Does it make sense that a guard would - with an equal chance - move forward or back? Or do a jump for every third step? I would not even have a behaviour for left/ right. Consider a change for something like

- do nothing (stop at position/ idle animation/ look around)
- move forward
- turn around
- jump

Now realistically most of the time the guard would move forward, lets start with 75% of the time. If it reaches a corner/ wall it will turn around with 100% chance, else it has maybe 10% while walking to turn around. Some with stopping, start with 10%. In 5% of the case the guard will jump. What does this change? You are not rolling anymore your behaviour in a range of [0, 3] but [0, 101]. And you would now compare it against the range. Afterwards you can tweak the ranges to make it more realistic and/ or add more behaviours. You don't need to add them to 100%, it just makes it easier (in this example all could be divided by 5 for a 15/2/2/1 distribution)

Comment: Thanks, this was kinda what I was missing.

Comment: By the way, why is InvokeRepeating inside Start() but not Update() ?

Comment: Because InvokeRepeating needs only to be called once and is calling the function by itself again.